# Expressing continuity in terms of seminorms

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be locally-convex topological vector spaces, with topologies given by families of seminorms $(p_i) _{i \in I}$ and $(q_j) _{j \in J}$, respectively.

If $L : X \to Y$ is a continuous linear operator, is its continuity equivalent to: $\exists p_i \ \exists q_j \ \exists C$ such that $q_j (Lx - Ly) \le C p_i (x - y)$?

I am seeing this in distribution theory quite a lot (for $Y = \Bbb C$) and I would like to know whether this is a general fact in locally-convex spaces (it clearly is in normed spaces).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Should be $q$ on the left side there, I suppose.  Post as answer?

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for catching the typo. Seems like a slightly lame answer but if you say so...

Comment: It's a straightforward question, and your straightforward answer addresses it precisely!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, continuity is equivalent to saying that for *every* $q$ there exist finitely many $p_1,\dots,p_n$ such that $$q(Lx)\le c\sum_{j=1}^np_j(x).$$

You may have been misled by the special case of distributions because in that case there is only one $q$ and any finite collection of $p_j$ is dominated by a single $p$.